# I need help interpreting diagnostic plots for a glm

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, diagnostic

I have used a function in the R package boot that give me diagnostic plots for a generalised linear model: `glm.diag.plots()`. I dont have experience with these, and thus don´t know how "strict" to be in assessing them. Can I rely on my model?

```
glm(formula = cbind(Hatched, Nothatched) ~ Temperature + Pesticide + 
    Temperature * Pesticide, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = hatching_success_eggs)

Coefficients:
                             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                   0.85984    0.17054   5.042 4.61e-07 ***
Temperature                   0.01750    0.01119   1.564  0.11789    
LowPesticide                 -0.46449    0.24456  -1.899  0.05753 .  
HighPesticide                -0.94613    0.23550  -4.018 5.88e-05 ***
Temperature:LowPesticide      0.02157    0.01606   1.343  0.17927    
Temperature:HighPesticide     0.04782    0.01577   3.033  0.00243 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 4311.9  on 562  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 4242.1  on 557  degrees of freedom
AIC: 5197.3

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

[image]